# Return string values of NodeList from a parsed XML doc

Tags: java, xml, xpath, nodelist

Given the xml snippet:

```
<AddedExtras>
    <AddedExtra Code="1234|ABCD" Quantity="1" Supplier="BDA"/>
    <AddedExtra Code="5678|EFGH" Quantity="1" Supplier="BDA"/>
    <AddedExtra Code="9111|ZXYW" Quantity="1" Supplier="BDA"/>
    <AddedExtra Code="9188|ZXYF" Quantity="1" Supplier="BDA"/>
    <AddedExtra Code="9199|ZXYG" Quantity="1" Supplier="BDA"/>
</AddedExtras>
```

And the following snippet which reads in the above xml as a parsed doc and uses an xpath expression to extract the 'Code' attribute:

```
public String getNodeValuesFromNodeList(Document doc, String expression){

NodeList nodeList = null;
    try {
        nodeList = (NodeList) xpath.compile(expression).evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
    } catch (XPathExpressionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return nodeList.toString();
}
```

The returned list is an Object (org.apache.xml.dtm.ref.DTMNodeList@58cf8f94) and not a list of Strings - how can I return the nodeList such that it returns the following as a list of Strings:

```
    Code="1234|ABCD
    Code="5678|EFGH
    Code="9111|ZXYW
    Code="9188|ZXYF
    Code="9199|ZXYG
```

Then, how can I return only the first 2 (as an example)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your XPath expression selects attributes, and you want the values of the attributes, then you can use a loop similar to the following:

```java
    List<String> codes = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); ++i) {
        Attr attr = (Attr)nodeList.item(i);
        codes.add(attr.getValue());
    }
```

Comment: To get the first two items from the list you could then do codes.sublist(0, 2)

Comment: What is Attr? I don't have that object and get an error.

Comment: @user2568374: it's [`org.w3c.dom.Attr`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Attr.html).